# Как сохранить всю структуру xml в переменную XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.</DeliveryNotes>
  <Items>
    <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
      <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
      <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
    </Item>
    <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
      <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
      <ShipDate>1999-05-21</ShipDate>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Хочу сохранить его в переменную xsl:variable, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать в другом преобразовании, но сохраняются только значения без тэгов.
Подскажите, как можно это реализовать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите код, как вы сейчас сохраняете в переменную.

Comment: Пошел другим путем, вызовом template и конкатенацией строк, сохранить весь xml в переменную не получилось. Код попытки немного позже.